Unit cell size for phonon modes
Based on this and some other literature I realize that the number of phonon modes is contingent upon the size of the unit cell.
I also understand that in using Quantum ESPRESSO, the study of defects necessitates a larger unit cell to bypass the periodic boundary conditions.
My question is that if I am studying phonon modes in crystal (say a perovskite) and want to make a comparison between the phonon modes for the pure cell and the defective cell, can I compare the phonon modes by using unit cells of different sizes?


can I compare the phonon modes by using unit cells of different sizes?

Sort of. The easiest thing to compare is densities of states. You can project it onto atoms to get even more detailed results.
If you want to compare "bands" from the disordered cell with the primitive cell, you have to 'unfold'. See e.g. here and here. This isn't really a band-by-band comparison... but conceptually disorder breaks the translational symmetry, so momentum is no longer a good quantum number and the concept of a band-structure is not really valid any more anyway (the use of a supercell for the disordered structure is an approximation).
In my opinion, a more valid way to do this type of analysis is to calculate the neutron scattering spectrum! See this answer in your linked question. Disclaimer: I am a neutron scatterer, so I am biased :). Neutrons don't know anything about your unitcell and scatter off the crystal according to the laws of nature. The scattering is measured in units of ~ $h/\lambda$, the physical momentum change. If you want to compare scattering from a disordered supercell to the primitive one, simply convert from wavelength to reciprocal lattice units of the primitive cell (i.e. $-\pi/2 < q \leq \pi/2$). If the disorder structure looks like the ordered one, the spectra will look similar! We do this for experiments all the time. Theoretically, it's easy. I did this with DFT calculations here for a distorted (not disordered) supercell to primitive cell. If you want to try this method, I recommend Euphonic to simulate neutron scattering spectra.
I hope this helps!
Ty

Thank you. That was exactly what I wanted. Just for the sake of completeness though, what other packages besides Euphonic do you recommend looking at?

I haven’t used any for unfolding… I think abinit can do it as part of the package! Some others might too. I don’t know of any other codes for simulating inelastic neutron scattering that I would recommend besides Euphonic.
